# Alternatives for Continuous Query Notifications in Oracle 12c CDB/PDB setup

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Long time trawler and massive fan of the site (you guys effectively taught me to code so big props to you all :D).

So as for my first question:

My company is currently developing an application that is back ended by an Oracle database, now in production this is going to be deployed in a 12c multi-tenant architecture. However the issue is our offshore development house had been developing and testing on 11g and incorrect infrastructure, something I have pushed to and mostly fixed since joining the compnay some months ago.

We have now hit a stumbling block, it has become apparent that our development house have no actual Oracle expertise and are SQL Server developers playing at Oracle, as such they are stuck on how to implement the functionality of **Continuous Query Notification (CQN)** in Oracle 12c given that this is deprecated in multi-tenant architecture.

I want to ask if anyone here has any suggestions for way to achieve the same functionality of a CQN in Oracle 12c?

The use of external scripts or solutions is doable, basically no limit on suggestions as we are at a stage where could potentially factor in any possible resolution.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this question is suitable for OTN.

Comment: Now, in Oracle 12.2: **DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION:** https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ARPLS/DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.htm#ARPLS201

Answer (score 1):

> how to implement the functionality of Continuous Query Notification (CQN) in Oracle 12c given that this is deprecated in multi-tenant architecture.

From the Readme Information for Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2), Section 2.2, "[Features Not Available or Restricted in This Release of Oracle Database 12.1.0.2](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/READM/chapter12102.htm#READM119)":

**Continuous Query Notification (CQN) is not available or is restricted for a multitenant container database (CDB)**

It is not the only feature unavailable/restricted, but one of the many features mentioned in that list.

> I want to ask if anyone here has any suggestions for way to achieve the same functionality of a CQN in Oracle 12c?

I don't think you could create an alternative at database level, you might just need to wait for further announcement from Oracle. If something could be done external to the database, you could do it at your own stake.

> our development house have no actual Oracle expertise and are SQL Server developers playing at Oracle

That seems to be a bigger problem.

Comment: Thanks, yeah we aware of the larger problem and are currently recruiting for an experienced Oracle DBA in our local office to vet work done by of external developers.
I mainly wondered if anyone had any suggestions of alternative methods to achieve something similar to the CQN functionality with 12c.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided much in way of details with how you are using CQN.  If, as an example, the front end app wants a notification if inserts or updates are made in a table then there a few things you could do.

- set up auditing on the table with "audit insert on  your_table;"
- create a custom view showing the actions on the table
- run a job which picks up on the new actions and notifies the app by whatever method